# D'Alembert Operator

Tags: operators, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, definition, differentiation

In which book or where can I find the derivation of the d'Alembert operator?
\begin{equation}
\Box \psi= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu \left( \sqrt{-g}\partial^\mu \psi \right) 
\end{equation}

Comment: It is just a definition.

Comment: Applying covariant derivative and Christtoofel symbols, can not be found?

Comment: Yes, it can, since another definition of the d'Alembert operator (which is more insightful, but maybe less convenient for computation) is $\Box = \nabla ^{\mu} \nabla _{\mu}$. Going from this defintion to yours, you will probably have to use several annoying identities involving the metric and Christoffel symbols.

Comment: This is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on an orientable Lorentzian manifold. A derivation can be found on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator

Answer (score 0):

Your box operator is actually called Laplace-Beltrami operator and it is defined as $\Box\equiv\nabla^m\nabla_m$, where $\nabla_m$ is covariant derivative. For a scalar you can write $\Box\psi=\nabla_m\partial^m\psi$. But $\partial ^m\psi$ is a vector, so you need to derive that divergence of a vector is
$$
\nabla_m V^m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\partial(V^m\sqrt{|g|})}{\partial x^m},
$$
then substitute $V^m=\partial^m\psi$.